# Why can't I include kallsyms.h in my Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to learn how to develop kernel modules, but some of my `#include` directives are failing.  I did some googling to figure out how to setup my Makefile, but I'm sure I must be doing something wrong.

Below are my `#include` directives:

```c
/* Filename: seafire.c */
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
```

My Makefile is as follows:

```
obj-m := seafire.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
curtico@ubuntu-vm:~/Documents/module$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-46-generic/build M=/home/curtico/Documents/module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-gerneric'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /home/curtico/Documents/module/seafire.o
/home/curtico/Documents/module/seafire.c:4:10: fatal error: linux/kallsyms.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <linux/kallsyms.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:257: /home/curtico/Documents/module/seafire.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1857: /home/curtico/Documents/module] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Below is relevant version info:

```
curtico@ubuntu-vm:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-vm 5.19.0-46-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
curtico@ubuntu-vm:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS OR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I assume my Makefile is the issue here.  What is the correct way to compile a Linux kernel module such that no header files are "missing"?

Comment: Obviously you can't use that header outside of kernel source tree.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on building external modules? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.17/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst#L77

Comment: @stark Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see any important differences between the examples you linked and the Makefile I wrote.

Comment: `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` is a symbolic link which only points to your kernel source if you built and installed the kernel on the current machine (which you didn't). Otherwise you must specify the correct path after -C. I linked directly to the line in the documentation describing this.

Comment: @stark I'm not sure what you mean.  When I run `file /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`, the output indicates that it is a symbolic link to `/usr/src/linux-headers-<version>-generic`.  I checked the contents of that directory, and it is filled with more symlinks to directories that presumably contain header files.  Additionally, the appropriate header packages are indeed installed using `apt`.  The line you linked to is nearly identical to what I have in the Makefile I posted in the original question.  Is there something else I need to do before this can work?  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then it sounds like your headers do not include kallsyms.h  Not sure why.